# To json from json crashes immediately

Tags: java, json, gson, android

The following snippet crashes with `Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING`

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();   
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();  
String jsonObjString = gson.toJson(customClassInstance, MyCustomClass.class);  
gson.fromJson(jsonObjString, MyCustomClass.class);  // Crashes here
```

Why? When I print the `jsonObjString` it seems fine.
And the encoding/decoding seems correct. What is the problem?

**Update:**

```
public class MyCustomClass {

    @SerializedName(“customer_city”)
    private String customerCity;

    @SerializedName(“customer_id”)
    private String customerId;

    private LocalDate entry;

    @SerializedName(“customer_income”)
    private double customerIncome;

    private String[] cards;


    @SerializedName(“customer_name")
    private String customerName;

}
```

Comment: what do u mean by "crashing"? is it throwing some exception, if yes, please post that too.

Comment: It is probably a mismatch between JsonString and the Java class.

Comment: @RamanShrivastava:The exception is mentioned in the OP

Comment: @Jagrut:But it is encode/decode in 2 lines. How can it be wrong?

Comment: What **is** your custom class...?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce:I can update OP with it, but if there was a problem with it (trivial class with strings) would I be getting the json string correctly like I do now in the line before the crash? When I printed the string is correct json

Comment: @Jim by your exception I would say your json is not correct. It clearly states an incorrect start. Can you show the json generated?

Comment: @Jim If your class object is not generic, try with `toJson(customClassInstance)`

Comment: @Jagrut:It is not generic and I tried that too. Same problem

Comment: @EpicPandaForce:Updated OP

Comment: @Jim Can you please post the content of `jsonObjString`?

Comment: Does it work without `private LocalDate entry;` ?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce:You are right. Without LocalDate it works! How can I fix this?

Comment: Well that depends on how it's by default serialized to String. Because apparently it serializes it as a string, but then tries to load it by default as an object, and it doesn't work. You'll need a custom type adapter for the type `LocalDate`. What is the JSON output?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce:`{“customer_city”:”ny”, “customer_id”:”1234”, “customer_income”:120000.00, “cards”:[“master card”, “visa”]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `LocalDate` requires a deterministic way of serializing and deserializing it. For that, you have to register a custom type adapter in your `Gson` instance.

```
   public class LocalDateAdapter extends TypeAdapter<LocalDate> {
     public LocalDate read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
       if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
         reader.nextNull();
         return null;
       }
       String xy = reader.nextString();
       return new LocalDate(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").parse(xy);
     }
     public void write(JsonWriter writer, LocalDate value) throws IOException {
       if (value == null) {
         writer.nullValue();
         return;
       }
       String xy = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(value.getTime());
       writer.value(xy);
     }
   }
```

You need something like that, although I'm not exactly sure about the API of `LocalDate`.

Then register it to your Gson instance

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
     .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateAdapter())
     .create();
```

Comment: (also worth noting that you should probably save it out as a `long` instead of a String, so that you don't end up in trouble with timezones.)